# How to fix changes in git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have added submodule to my project, I have added my file to it, then I have done commit. What I have to do now? I can't push changes because that submodule repository is not my, I haven't password from it, etc. Is it possible to push changes in submodule to my server?

Comment: what do you mean by "added submodule to my project" , you cloned it from remote repository ??

Comment: Yes, I cloned it from remote repository. I clicked in smartgit "submodule->add" and entered remote repository url

Comment: might be this question can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372625/git-how-to-push-submodule-to-a-remote-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update submodule source on server by simple push. Possible way to do this:

1. fork your submodule project (if license allow it)
2. push in that fork your changes
3. update submodule url to new fork repository.You can do this by editing `.gitmodules` file:

   ```
   [submodule "lib/Example"]
       path = lib/Example
       url = ../Example.git  # <-- here insert link to your fork
   ```

   Doing this in future you must update your fork manually, periodically doing pulls from upstream (original submodule project) repository
4. finally do `git submodule update`