# How to make GitHub project part of a larger solution on a repository level?

Tags: git, github

I'm doing a project that will have these 3 components (all working together):

- Custom server-side code
- Custom client-side code
- One 3rd party library that is a GitHub project (BSD licensed)

As part of the development, it is likely that I will make changes to the 3rd party library project and that I will want to contribute my changes back to the project owner, preferably via GitHub fork / pull request.

The question is, how do I structure my repository (repositories) if I don't want it to be entirely open-source and hosted on GitHub? If it were 100% closed-source, I would have one repository with 3 main folders, something like `ServerSide`, `ClientSide` and `LibraryXY` but I guess copying the contents of the 3rd party library to `LibraryXY` would make it difficult to contribute changes to it back to the project owner on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either `git submodule` or `git subtree` commands.

A submodule in a git repository is like a sub-directory which is really a separate git repository in its own right.  This is a useful feature when you have a project in git which depends on a particular versions of other projects. [see details](http://longair.net/blog/2010/06/02/git-submodules-explained/)

Subtrees allow subprojects to be included within a subdirectory
of the main project, optionally including the subproject's
entire history. For example, you could include the source code for a library
as a subdirectory of your application. [see details](http://psionides.eu/2010/02/04/sharing-code-between-projects-with-git-subtree/)

Based on your project structure, I would suggest you use `git subtree`

Comment: Thanks. From the description, submodule seems to be the thing that I am looking for - having 3 directories and one of them somehow configured to fetch the sources from GitHub sounds right. Will I be able to "push" changes made to that sources back to GitHub or is it one way only?

Comment: You should be able to do that: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814319/git-submodule-push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814319/git-submodule-push)

Comment: @Borek A submodule is a full-fledged repository on its own. So yes. Be aware that the `submodule` mechanism is not as well designed as other parts of git and can be a little confusing at times.