# git submodules cannot be pushed

Tags: git, github

I have a project which have a git submodule the project is hosted in github.com

i cloned the project, using

```
git clone git@github.com:myname/myproject.git
```

after that I did execute these,

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

and now if I do an update to the submodule codes I cant really push that to the submodule,

PS: i have access to both the project and the submodule, what can this be ?

thanks

Comment: this answered the question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814319/git-submodule-push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be at the submodule level to push:

```
cd path/to/submodule
git add -A && git commit && git push
cd -
```

One thing you may have to do is create or checkout a branch in the submodule and push that. You'll only have to do that if you are operating in headless mode. You could also tag and push that tag up.