# git - default push to --recurse-submodules=check

Tags: git, git-submodules

I always forget to push submodules. Sometimes I forget to add `--recurse-submodules=check` to `git push`. Even worse, others on my team might do the same. Is there a `git config` option we can set to make `check` the default?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try aliasing it.

```
git config alias.ps "push --recurse-submodules=check"
```

Then use

```
git ps
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm doing. But it would be better if we could default the real push to doing that.

Comment: Or if `alias.push` overrode the command, but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 25):

Git v2.7.0 adds support for the `push.recurseSubmodules` configuration option. It can be set to the same values as the `--recurse-submodules` command line options. For example:

```
git config push.recurseSubmodules check
```

means that subsequent invocations of `git push` will automatically check that submodules have been pushed.

Comment: See also the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814319/git-submodule-push)