# Enforce --recurse-submodules=on-demand for all clones of a repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

Given a Git repository with several submodules.
Is there a way to enforce all clients (read *clones*) of that repository to use the `--recurse-submodules=on-demand` option on pushing commits? I don't want to have the users manually add that flag to each `git push`.

Beside that, I will also set up an update hook on the server to enforce this policy, but that alone would make the users have to enter `--recurse-submodules=on-demand` each time they push commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet: the config "`push.recurseSubmodules`" proposed [in that patch](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/177992) didn't make it through.
Even if it had, that would mean each user need to configure his/her clone.

The only other solution is to define an alias (as in "[git - default push to `--recurse-submodules=check`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681936/git-default-push-to-recurse-submodules-check)").
Again, this is a per-user solution (no easy way to propagate that setting from one central repo to all its clone).

Comment: Thanks for the link to that patch. We'll probably take the alias route and annoy all group members to have that configured ;)