# how to prevent unpushed submodules in git

Tags: git, git-submodules

is there some hook script in git that will detect if the submodule source tree is available whenever you push to the main project? Intend to avoid people pushing a master project that has unpushed submodules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use (git 1.7.7+):

```
 git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

I present it in "[Git submodule push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/6309)", and it detects any submodule modification, to push it first, before pushing the main repo.

---

> Note that there are 2 options:

```
git push --recurse-submodules=check
git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
```

> Make sure all submodule commits used by the revisions to be pushed are available on a remote tracking branch.
>
> - If `check` is used git will verify that all submodule commits that changed in the revisions to be pushed are available on at least one remote of the submodule.
>     If any commits are missing the push will be aborted and exit with non-zero status.
> - If `on-demand` is used all submodules that changed in the revisions to be pushed will be pushed.
>     If on-demand was not able to push all necessary revisions it will also be aborted and exit with non-zero status.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git submodule foreach` to invoke any command for each submodule, so to check whether your branch is behind origin/master, run:

```
git submodule foreach git status
```

To push all your changes from submodules, run:

```
git submodule foreach git push
```

See: [`man git-submodule`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git-submodule).