# PyCharm/GitHub: Managing the directories of multiple repositories for the same project

Tags: git, github, directory, repository, pycharm

**Background:**  I'm currently working on a bioinformatics project.  I'm using PyCharm as an IDE and GitHub for version control.  I was wondering about my project structure...

**Setup:**  We have 2 repositories:

1. A main repo that houses all of our files and directories
2. And then we have a side repo that hosts our R-Shiny app/files/directores

The GitHub repo for the R-shiny app (2) is a mirror image of one of the directories in the main repo (1).  We will be doing constant maintenance on the R-Shiny app (hence the reason for 2 repos).

I will reference the PyCharm project AND the GitHub repo as (1) and (2) from here forward.

**Question:**  What is the best way to deal with this situation?

> **1.**  In my main project (1) directory is it safe to create a new PyCharm project (2)?
>   And then push/pull main project (1) + side project (2) to main project repo(1).  And then push/pull side project (2) to side project repo (2)
>
> **2.**  Create separate directories for both PyCharm Project.
>   I would have to copy/paste my directories from (2) and paste them appropriately into (1).
>   And then push/pull project (1) and project (2) separately.
>
> **3.**  Or should I just consolidate everything into one project/repository, and then create a separate branch for the R-Shiny app/directories?  I have no idea if this is possible or practical.
>
> **4.**  Other..

I want to find a better/standard/practical way to deal with this situation.  I'm not a novice programmer by any means.  But I've taught myself a lot by trial and error, so sometimes my methods are a bit unconventional.

Answer (score 1):

I often work with projects where I need to reference other directory trees that are also PyCharm projects. Usually I just add the reference as a `Content Root`. Open project 1, then go to `Preferences > Project > Project Structure > Add Content Root` and add the path to project 2.

You should now see both project 1 and 2 listed in `View > Tool Window > Project`.

Exclude the sub directory of project 1 (right-click `Mark Directory As > Excluded`), this will prevent classes, files and symbols in that location from showing up as duplicates in the `Navigate` searches.

PyCharm is smart about tracking multiple git repos in the same project, see `Preferences > Version Control`. Just don't nest git repos inside each other.

To compare your latest changes between project 1 and 2 select the folders in the Project Tool Window, right-click and choose `Compare Directories`.

To keep project 1 and 2 in sync you have a couple of options

- Use git submodules as suggested by @Pockets answer, note that casual git users might struggle with this setup. If you go this route then all the previous steps do not apply.
- Keep project 1 and 2 in separate repos. Don't duplicate project 2 inside project 1. Add path to project 2 subfolder to the `.gitignore` in project 1. Push from the project 2 content root and pull into the subfolder.
- Duplicate project 2 files inside 1. Use PyCharm `Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment` with `Type > Local or mounted folder`

Comment: Thanks!  I'm pretty familiar with PyCharms settings, so this all makes sense to me.  I've added project 2 to the content roots, but the system link is going to be hard to implement.  I have Windows with no admin rights...  Is there any other way to sync (project 2) with (project 1, sub directory project 2)?

Comment: I've edited the answer since symlinks is not an options on Windows.

Comment: Thank you!  I should have mentioned I'm using Windows for development.  I'm not going to be able to get to this solution today, but I will inform you when I've tried this out.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle this is with Git submodules, which allow you to include a reference to a specific commit of another repository in the parent repository. This has the added benefit of being able to version your dependencies: if you update something in R-shiny, those changes do not propagate up until you manually bring in those changes and know that the code in the parent repository supports the changes in the R-shiny stuff. tl;dr: your setup should have both as their own repos, with R-shiny included as a submodule of the other.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182903/git-subrepositories#42184866) for a more thorough explanation about how to use submodules.

Be warned: you say it's a bioinformatics project, so chances seem to be that the people who need to be able to view your code may not necessarily be the most proficient Git users - it might help to include scripts for them to get around.