# Git: how do I make sure I don't commit/push hashes to submodules which haven't been pushed to remote yet?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-commit, git-remote

I'm sure you know the situation but I don't know the correct wording:

I have a repository with a couple of submodules which I work on in the context of the main repository - i.e. I often have to change the content of the submodules rather than working on them somewhere else separately.

When I've added/committed changes to those submodules, quite often I commit/push the submodules new commit ID but forget to *push* the submodule itself.

Locally this is no problem and hard to identify but of course the build breaks because even the checkout goes wrong.

I know with git this situation is not easy to handle in a general way because of how remotes work but there *must* be approaches to avoid this situation.

What is yours? Is there a git intrinsic method?

Comment: Probably not the smartest but I almost always only add the changes that I want to commit to the staging area.

Comment: Pre-commit or pre-receive hooks: https://github.com/rodrigo-lima/submodule_checker

Comment: Pre-receive hook would hardly help — it's a server-side hook. Pre-commit hook with something like `git submodule foreach git push` is the way to go; `git push` on an updated submodule is a no-op.

Comment: @phd `pre-receive` hook could defiinitely help, if OP has authority to install `pre-receive` hooks in the remote repo, a `pre-receive` hook could reject all users from pushing a commit referencing a submodule commit which does not exist in the remote.

Comment: @Alderath Pushable remote is usually a bare repository, it doesn't contain working directory and submodules. How does a server-side hook in this situation check if submodules have been updated?

Answer (score 2):

You have [various local configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/6309) to make a simple git push to *also* include the submodules (meaning you are pushing the submodules and your main project, all in one go)

```
git config push.recurseSubmodules on-demand
git push
```