# Pushing submodules recursively throws "fatal: src refspec must name a ref" if containing project is not on master branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository with three submodules. The containing repository has two branches `master` and `develop`. All submodules only have one branch – the `master` branch.

When the containing repository is on the master branch, pushing to origin via `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` works as expected. Both the containing project as well as its submodules are pushed.

Now here is the problem. When the containing repository is on the `develop` branch, I am getting a problem when pushing via `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand`. The push operation is cancelled and an error message is printed.

Here is the full output I get from git:

```
$ git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand
fatal: src refspec 'refs/heads/develop' must name a ref
fatal: process for submodule 'Frameworks/OpenLearnWareClient' failed
```

I can mitigate this problem by first pushing changes in each submodule manually and then pushing the containing repository. This however is very tedious and defeats the purpose of `--recurse-submodules=on-demand`.

Here is my `.gitmodules` file:

```
[submodule "Frameworks/OpenLearnWareKit"]
    path = Frameworks/OpenLearnWareKit
    url = git@github.com:kaiengelhardt/OpenLearnWareKit.git
    branch = master
[submodule "Frameworks/OpenLearnWareClient"]
    path = Frameworks/OpenLearnWareClient
    url = git@github.com:kaiengelhardt/OpenLearnWareClient.git
    branch = master
[submodule "Frameworks/KEFoundation"]
    path = Frameworks/KEFoundation
    url = git@github.com:kaiengelhardt/KEFoundation.git
    branch = master
```

I am using git version 2.20.1 (Apple Git-117).

Does anybody know what is going wrong here and how to make recursive pushing work?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/10309266) might be of some help

Comment: @gavin That’s what OP is already doing but it fails in this case.

Comment: This absolutely seems like a bug with git itself. Still getting this with git version 2.24.0 on macOS mojave. I don't know how to file a bug with git, but all anyone would need to do is link to this SO question.

Comment: Just found out, I can successfully run `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand` on my `dev` branch, and it successfully pushed a new commit to a submodule. (Note: no PR workflow was used here, just pushing directly to my own branch)

Comment: I got this error while using third-party submodules and found I could get the push to go through with `--recurse-submodules=no`. Obviously that's not the case in the OP, but leaving this comment for future searchers. My submodules both have detached heads.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell (I’d like to be proved wrong!) there is no “recursive push” for submodule branches. In general, [branches in submodules are an odd beast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1777854/1968) and don’t work the same way as regular branches in Git.

A close workaround is to use the `git submodule foreach` command to perform the pushes. This is still annoying but at least it solves the “tedious” aspect. Combine the commands as follows to ensure that a failed submodule push aborts the parent module push:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git push' &&
git push
```

As far as I can tell this is essentially equivalent to passing `--recurse-submodules=on-demand`, but works with branches.

Comment: This sadly doesn't work if I have dependencies (to whose repos I don't have write access) as submodules. `--recurse-submodules=on-demand` just skips these, because I don't commit anything in those repos. But `git push` in the submodule asks for a password (which I don't have and don't want to have...)

Comment: @TS Unfortunately I don’t have a solution for this case. **But** in general you should mirror all submodule remotes. That is, submodules in your project should have remotes that you control and for which you therefore have push rights; otherwise your project is fragile: if the upstream maintainer of one of your submodules decides to delete their repository, or otherwise makes destructive changes to the repository, you’re screwed.