# What is git push's default behavior toward submodules when push.recurseSubmodules is unset?

Tags: git

The `git-push` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---recurse-submodulescheckon-demandonlyno) is pretty clear on the four options (using `--recurse-submodules`) for `push`'s behavior when submodules are present:

- `check`: Make sure submodule commits needed by the parent have been pushed; abort push if they have not
- `on-demand`: Push all needed submodule commits before pushing parent commits (and fail if any fail)
- `only`: Push only submodules; do not push the parent
- `no` (or `--no-recurse-submodules`): Do not push submodules.

But what is the default? If no `--recurse-submodules` option is present, no `--no-recurse-submodules` option is present, and no `push.recurseSubmodules` configuration value is set, what happens? And is it the same for all Git versions?

**Appendix**

The documentation contains a *hint* that the default is `no`:

> A value of no or using --no-recurse-submodules can be used **to override the push.recurseSubmodules configuration variable when no submodule recursion is required**. (emphasis added)

So if the `no` option is needed only when `push.recurseSubmodules` is set, this implies that when `push.recurseSubmodules` is *unset*, `no` is the default behavior. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned in "[Git submodule push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878273/6309)" that:

When `push.recurseSubmodules` is set to `no`, then **default behavior of ignoring submodules when pushing is retained**.

That suggests `no` is indeed the default behavior.

Comment: When fetching, on the other hand... https://github.com/git/git/blob/0aae918dd929862d3ce0ea2960897787bb269a3b/submodule.c#L1424-L1435