# How to push cloned submodule within my repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

I maintain my private repo `A` and have its clone locally. Within it I cloned my friend's repo `B` as using `git clone`. Then, I added it as a submodule using

```
git submodule add ...
```

To which I got

```
B already exists in the index
```

Now, I wish to push it to my repo `A` and so, I `cd` into `B` and commit+push. But I get permission issues:

```
remote: Permission to myFriend/B.git denied to me.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myFriend/B.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What am I doing wrong even after following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814351/9625777)

Comment: You won't be able to push it unless you're a contributor of this repo on GitHub (which you're not, but luckily you can ask your friend for it). Yet a better solution is to *fork* this repository on your account and the add it as your submodule, which you'll be able to freely change and push

Comment: ...of course assuming you're a law-abiding citizen and you won't violate the friend repository's license with your changes